# Open/close low voltage AC circuit with 3.3 VDC signal

Tags: circuit-design

I have a small circuit, containing 16 VAC (50 Hz) source, AC device and button  which closes the circuit (pressed - device is working, released - device stops). I would like to replace the button with something that can be controlled with 3.3 V (planning to connect it to Raspberry Pi). Button is pressed around 10 times per day, for a few seconds.

Can I use circuit with triac and optocoupler that controls 230 VAC shown below? If I can, can you suggest how to adjust values for transistors, capacitors and so on, to work with 16 VAC?

[image: AC switching circuit]

Also, if there is a better/simpler solution, please include it in answer.

I suppose I can use relay for this but I would like to use something that doesn't create clicking sound.

Comment: Probably not, they may need more than 16V to switch. I'd be looking at relays (probably solid state relays designed for 3.3V).

Comment: Thanks for your input. They were my last option, if there isn't any good alternative. I will probably end up using them in the end :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this, however you should use the non-zero crossing type of optocoupler. The zero crossing type have an inhibit voltage that can be as high  as 20V. One type would be the [MOC3023](http://optoelectronics.liteon.com/upload/download/DS-70-99-0019/MOC302X%20series%20201606.pdf).

Be aware that the triac will drop a volt or two so you won't get all the voltage on your load. You don't mention the current or other load characteristics so I can't comment further on what might be a better solution, though if the current is low (such as 500mA) you should consider an opto-MOS SSR.

You can reduce the resistor to pin 6 to 51 ohms and leave the rest. The snubber (39 ohms/10nF) is optional particularly if you have a high voltage triac and a benign load. Use a relatively sensitive gate triac (quadrants I and III only are important). A 20mA gate trigger will cause you to lose ~1V at the beginning of each cycle as well as the conduction voltage drop. That's not much power because the maximum dv/dt of a sine wave is where it crosses zero, but it can cause EMI and may affect some loads.

Sometimes other trigger circuits are used such as "picket fence" pulse triggering through a pulse transformer or a DC-DC converter driving the gate and providing isolation.

The opto-MOS type of switch behaves more like a low value resistor when it is on.

Comment: Thank you. As soon as I can take time to connect and test optocoupler-triac solution, I will comment/accept your answer. I also measured the current, its 1.04 A. Does that mean I cannot use SSR (since it is greater than 500 mA)?

Comment: Certainly not. There are appropriate types such as the 60V/3A rated [TLP3545](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=12663&prodName=TLP3545). It's okay for 1A up to 85 degrees C.

Comment: It's working! I'm using MOC3023 for optocoupler like you said, BTA06-600C for triac and 56 ohms resistor near pin 6. The rest is as in the picture. It works with and without the snubber. Thanks again for your suggestions and explanations.